# Angular 17 SwUpdate "Property 'available' does not exist on type 'SwUpdate'"

Tags: angular

Just update to latest version of Angular 17 and @angular/service-worker@17.1.0 and now this message pop up as I started. I was running @angular/service-worker@16.2.12 before.

```
Error: src/app/app.component.ts:44:21 - error TS2339: Property 'available' does not exist on type 'SwUpdate'.

44       this.swUpdate.available.subscribe(() => {
```

This is my code:

```
constructor(
...
    private swUpdate: SwUpdate
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

 ...

    if (this.swUpdate.isEnabled) {
      this.swUpdate.available.subscribe(() => {
        window.location.reload();
      });
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Couldn't find anything regards this problem with new version.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the documentation in version `16.2.12`, the `available` property was marked as deprecated and has indeed been removed in version 17.

The documentation suggests using the `versionUpdates` Observable instead

```js
/**
 * Emits an `UpdateAvailableEvent` event whenever a new app version is available.
 *
 * @deprecated Use {@link versionUpdates} instead.
 *
 * The behavior of `available` can be replicated by using `versionUpdates` by filtering for the
 * `VersionReadyEvent`:
 *
 * {@example service-worker-getting-started/src/app/prompt-update.service.ts
 * region='sw-replicate-available'}
 */
readonly available: Observable<UpdateAvailableEvent>;
```

Looking at the doc, I would replace the code with something like :

```
this.swUpdate.versionUpdates.subscribe((event) => {
  if (event.type === "VERSION_READY") {
        window.location.reload();
  }
});
```